# Where does get_and_drive come from?

Tags: uvm

I found almost every driver that extends from `uvm_driver` has task `get_and_drive` like below. I checked the uvm source code and uvm_cookbook, but I didn't find `get_and_drive`. It seems it is not a uvm rule; it is more likely a convention. Who first used the task named `get_and_drive()`, and why do almost all people use the name `get_and_drive` in their driver?

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
     get_and_drive();
endtask : run_phase

task get_and_drive();
     forever begin
          seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
          send_to_dut(req);
          seq_item_port.item_done();
     end
endtask : get_and_drive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the `example/integrated/ubus` directory, in the `ubus_master_driver` you'll see a method that's called `get_and_drive()`. If you go back to OVM, you'll see that in XBUS example also defined the same method in the `xbus_master_driver`.

Since most people learn by example, I guess the convention just stuck. I think other methodology sites (like [Verification Academy](https://verificationacademy.com/)) also promote the same convention.